# Regex To Match Everything Except Encryption Lines

Tags: regex

I have been trying to craft a regex that matches everything in a file except for the lines that contain encrypted lines.

File example:

```
random text0
set private-key "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
 MIIFHDBOBgesdfsfsf242asdasdasdasdasdasdaDDADADADASS2
 sdfsfdsfsfs342424r2aa423412edqwdadawdawa1awdsadaAAAA
 242342342da==
set private-key "-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
random text1
random text2
```

Using regex I want to match all random text except for the chunk of text displaying encrypted lines.

I crafted the following regex but it doesn't seem to work:

```
^(?!.*(\bset\s+private-key\s+"-----BEGIN\s+ENCRYPTED PRIVATE\s+KEY-----\b.*\bset private-key\s+"-----END\s+ENCRYPTED\s+PRIVATE\s+KEY-----\b)).*
```

----EDIT-----

File Example 2:

```
test12
test22
test44
        set private-key "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- 
MasdasdasdasdasEq1XnGfVONkCAggA 
KpYsdfdasdasdasdafvpFFoUanRXimMv+d9n6YiahiJ4xqPnMOelMGE dC8FRR92rpsVuZiLtgGP5A== 
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"

test2
test3
```

Comment: What language do you use? It might be easier to do a regex search & replace to delete stuff you do not want, such as this in JavaScript regex using `g` flag: `let result = text.replace(/\bset private-key\s+"-+BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-+[\s\S]*?\bset private-key\s+"-+END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-+[\r\n]*/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to match the encrypted part, and capture other lines in a capture group.

```
^set\s+private-key\s+"-----BEGIN\s+ENCRYPTED PRIVATE\s+KEY-----(?:\r?\n(?!set private-key).*)*\r?\nset\s+private-key.*|(.+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `set\s+private-key\s+"-----BEGIN\s+ENCRYPTED PRIVATE\s+KEY-----` Match the first line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!set private-key).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `set private-key`
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `set\s+private-key.*` Match the line that starts with `set private-key`
- `|` Or
- `(.+)` Match 1+ times any char in **group 1**

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n9CUae/1).

Or to match multiple lines in group 1:

```
^set\s+private-key\s+"-----BEGIN\s+ENCRYPTED PRIVATE\s+KEY-----(?:\r?\n(?!set private-key).*)*\r?\nset\s+private-key.*|(.+(?:\r?\n(?!set\s+private-key).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/418tQL/1)

Comment: Hello, once again thank you so much for the help, I was trying to customize the regex you provided to match "File Example 2" and was not successful, are you able to please help? I've customised your regex for the new example, but cant seem to get it to exclude the encryption: ^set\s+private-key\s+"-----BEGIN\s+ENCRYPTED PRIVATE\s+KEY-----(?:\r?\n(?!set private-key).*)*\r?\n-----END\s+ENCRYPTED\s+PRIVATE\s+KEY-----".*|(.+(?:\r?\n(?!-----END\s+ENCRYPTED\s+PRIVATE\s+KEY-----).*)*)

Comment: @Help Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/UZ8rwu/1 or https://regex101.com/r/VRdGLL/1

Answer (score 1):

This suits your purpose:

```
^(?! \w+=*$).*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/c71EAl74rTrFaG).